# XAML Custom Time Format

Tags: xaml, grid, windows-10

I have a Grid with cells which contain values in seconds (i.e. 34000 or 2346).

I need to be able to convert that to "1d 12h 35m". That in itself is fine but when sorting the grid it treats them as strings, meaning 11d 23h 35m will come ahead of 1d 7h 3m.

Is there a way to still treat the cell behind as the integer of seconds?

See below for binding code:

```
ServiceClient sc = new ServiceClient();
            var Result = await sc.getTeamsAsync("MyTeam");

            foreach(Team row in Result)
            {
                double Seconds = 0;
                double.TryParse(row.TimeLeft, out Seconds);
                TimeSpan timeLeft = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)Seconds);
                row.TimeLeft = (timeLeft .Days + "d " + timeLeft .Hours + "h " + timeLeft .Minutes + "m");
            }

            this.DataGrid.ItemsSource = Result;
```

The results are coming from a service and they get binded to the DataGrid as above.

Comment: Should it be a pure xaml based solution or is a solution with codebehind also okey?

Comment: Code behind is fine, preferred even.

Comment: I'll hopefully have time to give you an example within 24 hours. But yes, it's very much possible :)

Comment: Btw, could you include an example of one of these XAML cells? Would be interesting to see :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's gonna take longer. We have kind of a situation over here...

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry for this late reply.

Here's how I would do it:

I'm assuming that you have access to the source of the "Teams" class?
I would make it into a comparable class, and then bind to a string that is dynamically generated (in this case instead of binding to TimeLeft I would bind to TimeLeftText).

I would also change TimeLeft into an int so that it's a lot easier to handle.

```
public class Team : IComparable
{
    private int TimeLeft { get; set; }
    public string TimeLeftText
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan timeLeft = new TimeSpan(0, 0, TimeLeft);
            return (timeLeft.Days + "d " + timeLeft.Hours + "h " + timeLeft.Minutes + "m");
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Team))
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        var comparer = (Team)obj;

        return TimeLeft.CompareTo(comparer.TimeLeft);
    }
}
```

This way it will be presented as "1d 5h 47m" but when it's sorted the actual seconds are going to be compared against each other and the result will be a lot more logical.

Once again, sorry for the late reply. Hope it's not too late and to some help to you :)